# How to fetch data without a duplicate entry by using limit and order by

Tags: mysql, sql

Here we are using limit for pagination

This was my scenario

I have a post with likes in my database .
Am fetching data by ordering maximum number of likes post with the limit 0,5

The problem is

we have shown the data by maximum likes with limit 0,5 for first page say as example

```
1) post:hello,Likes:8
2) post:hello1,Likes:8
3) post:hello2,Likes:7
4) post:hello3,Likes:6
5) post:hello4,Likes:5
```

Now for second page an calling 5,5

```
6) post:hello5,Likes:5
7) post:hello6,Likes:5
8) post:hello7,Likes:4
9) post:hello8,Likes:3
10) post:hello9,Likes:2
```

But if in case the post post:hello5 got Likes:8 at the time of going second page means  am getting the duplicate,

Because the first page has only two likes 8 but when going secong page it has three likes 8 so when limiting the data of 
the post of already fetch in page1 and page2 will be same 
the out put like this

When running first page

```
1) post:hello,Likes:8
2) post:hello1,Likes:8
3) post:hello2,Likes:7
4) post:hello3,Likes:6
5) post:hello4,Likes:5
```

Second page

```
6) post:hello4,Likes:5
7) post:hello5,Likes:5
8) post:hello6,Likes:5
9) post:hello7,Likes:4
10) post:hello8,Likes:3
```

See here the page 1 and 2 has same data (post:hello4,Likes:5) because when going to call second page like8 has three data to when getting mysql query with limit 5 it makes the duplicate of already fetch data

this was the post will got to third page (post:hello9,Likes:2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should realize one thing:

**this is probably what you want.**

Consider loading page1 at time X. How long will you then spend reviewing results from page 1 before going to page 2? Is it few microseconds? then it is very unlikely order will change in that time. Is it few minutes? Results would then be outdated, when viewing the next page. And how do you decide it is time to update search and show new updated results?

If you still insist on solving this, I suggest making new table

```
CREATE TABLE likes_search_orders(search_id varchar(255) not null, post_id bigint(20) not null, order_id biging(20) not null)
```

set unique index to `search_id-post_id` and proceed with following algorithm:

1. create random search_id (like md5(rand(0,1000000)."-".time()))
2. run:

   `INSERT INTO likes_search_orders (search_id, post_id, order_id) SELECT "search_id", post_id,  row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) FROM table_with_likes ORDER BY likes DESC`
3. use:

   `SELECT l.* FROM table_with_likes l INNER JOIN likes_search_orders o ON o.post_id = l.id AND o.search_id = "search_id" ORDER BY o.order_id DESC LIMIT 5,5`

Every time you create new search ID, you "freeze" the DB in the state it was at that given instant (at least the order of the things, you could possibly include likes as well into likes_search_orders, and then you would have even exact likes count at that given time)

I would also suggest creating table with searches, where you store search_id and date when it was created. You can then setup a cron to clean up old searches from DB so that they dont bloat up DB

Comment: Thanks for your idea friend. But we have million users using our website. so user search by keyword hello,  some user search text another keyword. Ho we can resolve for bulk user searching . Instead of new table can i use redis. But can it be solve for N no of users?

Comment: As long as users are involved, it means they will take some time to process the info on each page. So by the time they click on next, lots of things will have changed. There is no way NOT to replicate some data in DB and keep track of past and future states at the same time. note that locking table is not an option, locking is not inended for such long intervals.

Comment: So i have to track all past search of every individual user. And flush it once done or gone for next search,

Comment: yes, I would set up a cron to delete all past searches after say 24 hours. That is why I suggested another table for searches where you can keep track of search_id, time of creation, maybe user_id or some other tracking_id that can map search to a given user.

Comment: One extra advantage this offers is that users can share searches easily. I can send to somebody top-pages.php?search_id=876756453546567 and he will see the same results I do. Plus if initial search is expensive, this way you actually save resources.